# Having trouble with python inputs

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to programming and found an exercise that has you make a game. Basically, the program asks for 3 inputs: stop, start, and exit. Start makes the car start, stop makes the car stop, and exit is self explanatory. However, if you input start when the car is already started, it'll tell you the car is started, and so on. However, when I put an input into the terminal, nothing shows up. Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
started = False

carstate = str(input())

while carstate != "exit":
    if carstate == "start":
        if started == False:
            started == True
            print("Car has started... ready to go!")
        if started == True:
            print("Car has already started")
    elif carstate == "stop":
        if started == False:
            print("Car is already stopped!")
        if started == True:
            started == False
            print("Car is stopped")

if carstate == "exit":
    sys.exit()
if carstate == "help":
    print("Start - starts the car")
    print("Stop - stops the car")
    print("Exit - exits the game")
```

Comment: I believe you mean to get the input again in the while loop

Comment: you do not require the inner if statement after checking for carstate == "start": remove the `if started == 'False':`...

Comment: Btw, you don't need `str(input())`, since `input()` already returns a string. (You only need to convert type if you're trying to convert the input to int, or float, or some other non-string type)

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

The first issue here is, since `carstate = input()` is not inside the while loop, your program only calls for the user input once. To ask for the user input multiple times, you should put it inside like this:

```py
carstate = ""

while carstate != "exit":
    carstate = input()

    # ...
```

So, the program will continue to ask the user for input.

The second issue is the difference between `=` and `==`. `=` is used when you want to assign a value to a variable, while `==` is used when you want to compare something to a variable. So, when you say `started == True`, you should really be using `=`.

In addition, you should place the help block also inside the while loop, otherwise it will never get executed.

So the final code should be something like:

```py
import sys

started = False

carstate = ""

while carstate != "exit":
    carstate = input()
    if carstate == "start":
        if started == False:
            started = True
            print("Car has started... ready to go!")
        elif started == True:
            print("Car has already started")
    elif carstate == "stop":
        if started == False:
            print("Car is already stopped!")
        elif started == True:
            started = False
            print("Car is stopped")
    elif carstate == "help":
        print("Start - starts the car")
        print("Stop - stops the car")
        print("Exit - exits the game")

if carstate == "exit":
    sys.exit()
```

[Working example](https://repl.it/@mcparadip/TremendousPotableVaporware)

Comment: why `str(input())` when `input()` returns a string?

Comment: Glad I could help! If you don't mind, could you please click the checkmark next to the answer to mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

You ask for user input at the beginning, and then do the while loop. As you don't ask again for a different action in the while, it loops with "Car as started... ready to go!". You must do another "input()" inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

Your current code gets likely stuck inside the while loop. If you enter the loop by inputting `start` you will not get anything printed, nor any chance to change that.

Another note goes for the two additional state checks for `exit` and `help`. I would include those (or at least the `help` one) inside the main `while` loop.

And in two instances I am sure you wanted to use the assignment `=` rather than the equality check `==`. And some other cleanup :-)

Something like this should do:

```
started = False

carstate = ""  # initialize empty, we will ask for input at every iteration

while carstate != "exit":
    carstate = input()  # ask what we want to do next
    if carstate == "start":
        if started == False:
            started = True  # here you want to make an assignment (use '=' not '==')
            print("Car has started... ready to go!")
        elif started == True:  # change to "elif", so it avoids double prints
            print("Car has already started")

    elif carstate == "stop":
        if started == False:
            print("Car is already stopped!")
        elif started == True:  # change to "elif", so it avoids double prints
            started = False  # here you want to make an assignment (use '=' not '==')
            print("Car is stopped")

    elif carstate == "help":
        print("Start - starts the car")
        print("Stop - stops the car")
        print("Exit - exits the game")

if carstate == "exit":
    sys.exit()
```

Might be able to try it here: https://onlinegdb.com/S1gJ6lRGL

Answer (score 0):

When you first start the program, you only ask for input once, when you first ask for `carstate`. If it doesn't redefine `carstate` on every iteration, `carstate = input()`, then it will only keep the original initialization of it.

Also, even when it does, the part where it checks if `started == True` and then sets it to `True` if it is, you're comparing `==` instead of redefining `=`. This means it will never set it to `True`.

Another thing is that when you ask if it's `False`, the next `if` should be an `elif`, otherwise it'll trip both the first time around. An example, using the only `if`s and not an `elif`:

```
>>> start
Car has started... ready to go!
Car has already started
>>> start
Car has already started
```

Using the elif:

```
>>> start
Car has started... ready to go!
>>> start
Car has already started
```

You'll also need to import `sys` at the top, so it won't return a name error when it tries to run `sys.exit()`.

```py
import sys

started = False
carstate = ""

while carstate != "exit":
    carstate = input()  # asking for input each iteration.

    if carstate == "start":
        if started == False:
            started = True  # we're setting it, not comparing it.
            print("Car has started... ready to go!")

        elif started == True:  # remember the elif
            print("Car has already started")

    elif carstate == "stop":
        if started == False:
            print("Car is already stopped!")

        elif started == True:
            started = False
            print("Car is stopped")

    if carstate == "help":
        print("Start - starts the car")
        print("Stop - stops the car")
        print("Exit - exits the game")

if carstate == "exit":
    sys.exit()
```

Hope that helps.